# AJAX pager with 2 forms on page

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I have a custom search form on my website that pulls data from a 2nd drupal site, and the form utilizes AJAX to show results as the form is being filled out. I'm using a pager that also utilizes AJAX.

I also have a second form on the page that sends empty values to the submit function in order to "display all".

The problem is that with 2 forms on the page, the pager links don't do anything. They look correct but don't respond. If you do a search and then refresh the page, the 2nd form is no longer on the page and the pager works fine.

You can try it out here: http://www.adoptionhelp.org/find-a-family.

How can I get this pager to work for either form? Or, barring that, how do I otherwise create a "view all" button to submit empty values on my form?

Comment: After some more testing it seems that the first time I do a search, the pager doesn't work. If I refresh the page, or navigate away and come back, the pager starts working.
Here is a paste of the javascript I think may be the culprit, I didn't write it and am admittedly confused by it: http://drupalbin.com/20834

Comment: And I've confirmed the only difference in the output of the working page and not working version is the form_build_id of the form, and a random bit added to the end of lightbox's JS (not used here). Not surprising since that is recreated whenever the form is rendered. Still feeling stuck at step 1 :(

Comment: Problem goes away when I remove the second "view all families" form from the page. Now lost on step 2! Woohoo!